# Dynamic string formatting in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, format

I created log method that accept string. When I want to use it I write something like:

```
Log(string.Format("Message {0}", AdditionalInfo));
```

How should I implement `Log` method in order to be able to use string `Format` but do not have to write it explicitly in method arguments:

```
Log("Message {0}", AdditionalInfo);
```

I use .net 2.0

Comment: Thank you for fast answers :)

Comment: now feel free to watch the fight :)

Comment: @Zruty: LOL, guess we can argue the whole day about this...

Comment: I hope someone who has the privileges clears this question after we're done having fun

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public void Log(string formatString, params object[] parameters)
{
    Log(String.Format(formatString, parameters));
}
```

Comment: This site is named for a reason :)
Anyway, you are wrong. At least C# 4.0 distinguishes these overloads of `Log()` and do not cause infinite recursion

Comment: @Darin Not really, the functions have different parametres.

Comment: @Zruty, @Nubsis, are you sure? Did you test the code? Because I did. And I did in using C# 4.0.

Comment: I verified it before posting my answer, and it worked OK. What's the code you were testing on?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: If it went into an infinite loop, you only tested half the code.

Comment: I haven't tested it but it doesn't make sense to be that `Log (string, object)` would be the same as `Log(string)`. But if it is, then I retract my statement.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Yes, you probably didn't have the Log(string) overload, which the original poster seemed to have.

Comment: @Nubsis: the key is the `params`. This allows zero to n parameters. If only the method is defined as shown above, it will be an endless recursion.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void Log(string format, params object[] args)
{
    DoTheLog(string.Format(format, args));
}
```

Comment: Ouch, failing to overload the `Log` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Log(string format, params object[] args)
{
  Log(string.Format(format, args));
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Huh? Please explain why YOU think recursion (which is not even the case here) is bad.

Comment: This is an endless recursion. That's the problem! At least if there is no method `Log(string message)`

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: That is assuming `Log(string)` is not defined, but clearly the OP has the method defined...

Comment: @leppie: IMHO it should be told that this causes an endless recursion if the overload is missing, because it is not obvious to many.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: It is not my problem that people cant read the question correctly, sorry.

Comment: @leppie: Being a bit arrogant today, are we?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Please have a look at the implementation of `Console.WriteLine` (or `Write`).

Comment: That is probably a poor example. A `TextWriter` derived type would be better.

Comment: @leppie: What for? What do you want to prove?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
public void Log(string format, params object[] arguments)
{
    string message = string.Format(format, arguments);
    // Do something with message.
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could perhaps write a wrapper for your Log method. I hope something like this works.

```
public void Log(string format, object args)
{
    Do_Log(string.Format(format, args))
}
```

Now you can have Do_Log() as private and not expose it to consumers of your class.

Comment: -1: I think the question has bee answered enough, no need to just 'copy' the other responses...