# How to set args for a method?

Tags: c#, args

In my properties, I have several bools called `Username`, `Frames`, `Time`, and `Rerecords`. Also, there is a string called `StringFormat`. I will explain further in a moment.

I have an object called User with variables(is this the right word?) `User.Username`, `User.Frames`, `User.Time`, `User.Rerecords`. Each variable is a `string`, `int`, `int`, `int` respectively.

Finally, I have a method:

```
public void Display(string stringFormat, params object[] args)
{
    // stringFormat = Properties.Settings.Default.Format
    lbl_Display.Text = string.Format(stringFormat, args);
}
```

I wish uses the `User` variables as the args IF the property variables of the same names are `True`.

How can I do this? Currently, my research has lead me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304279/dynamic-string-formatting-in-c-sharp), but it hasn't been of any help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
I did it with some spaghetti code, to simulate the response:

```
public void Display()
{
    // spaghetti code - Fix later
    NumberConverter nc = new NumberConverter();

    List<bool> settings = new List<bool>
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Username,
        Properties.Settings.Default.Frames,
        Properties.Settings.Default.Time,
        Properties.Settings.Default.Rerecords
    };

    List<string> args = new List<string> { };
    if (settings[0])
        args.Add(compList[listIndex].Username);
    if (settings[1])
        args.Add(compList[listIndex].Frames.ToString());
    if (settings[2])
        args.Add(nc.FormatTime(compList[listIndex].Frames));
    if (settings[3])
        args.Add(compList[listIndex].Rerecords.ToString());

    lbl_Display.Text = string.Format(Properties.Settings.Default.Format, args.Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Could you not do `public void Display(string stringFormat, User user)`

Comment: "IF the property variables of the same names are True" How can the properties be true if they are string, int, int and int?

Comment: If not `Display(stringFormat, new object[] {User.Username, User.Frames, User.Time, User.Rerecords})`

Comment: As an example, if `Properties.Settings.Default.Username = True`, I wish to include `User.Username` in the args, so on so forth for the other 4 bools, if that makes sense.

Comment: I added some spaghetti code to explain how I wish for it to simulate. There has to be a better way to do this

Comment: Instead of using args use `StringBuilder` and do `lbl_Display.Text = stringBuilder.ToString()`

Comment: @Matt Oh? I have never used StringBuilder. Could you provide an example?

Comment: replace `List<string> args = new List<string> { };` with `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: Then replace `args.Add` with `sb.Append`

Comment: Oh, I see! Interesting, I will give it a go now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Single Responsibility Principle violation.  You need a UserFormatter class that stores the preferences.  It constructor needs to take the config settings, it needs a Format() method that takes User.  You surely need only one instance of it, so you can make it static to find it back easily.